# From synchronous flow to asynchronous flow dilemma

Tags: actionscript-3, air

As a PHP programmer I'm very habituated to the fact that the program flow goes line by line, if I call function1() that have to return some value I know the program wont continue until that function makes a return.

Now, im developing a AS3 app using AIR, I need to download some images if some conditions are met, don't know how many, so im using a For like this:

```
for (var w:int=0; w < newData_array[2]['content'].length; w++ ) {
    for (var j:int=0; j < oldData_array[2]['content'].length; j++ ) {
        if((oldData_array[2]['content'][j]['id'] == newData_array[2]['content'][w]['id']) &&  (oldData_array[2]['content'][j]['last_mod'] != newData_array[2]['content'][w]['last_mod'])){
            //need to download a image...
        }
    }       
}
```

As you can see im just comparing each element from each array (**newData_array** and **oldData_array**). If the condition met, I need to download something, for that I'm using **URLloader** and as you know this function is asynchronous, adding a listener, an event will be triggered when the download is complete, the problem is very clear, since the urlloader wont stop the for cycle (like I would expect on a PHP alike language) I'm just going to download a bunch of images at the same time creating a disaster because I wont know when to save. So I need to use by any mean the listener, but since I'm not very habituated to this kind of procedures I'm pretty munch stuck.

Im not interested on the save to disk routines, that part is pretty much done, I just want to understand how I should structure this algorithm to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using an third party library that pretty munch handles this problem.

https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader

Answer (score 0):

This annoyed me too, but one has to realize that you can't do something to something that doesn't exist in memory yet, and these loading operations can take quite some time.  Being a single-threaded stack, Flash Player's load operations would require that the entire interface to freeze during the load (if restricted to the loop).

Obviously there's data available to the loop that dictates what you do with the image.  The solution I've been using is create a custom load function that starts the load, and returns a proxy image . Your loop gets a container back and you can freely place your image where you want.

In the meantime, your loader listener has kept track of the active images loading, and their associated proxies.  When loaded, swap the image in.

Your loop would look something like this...

```
for (var w:int in newData_array[2]['content']) {
    for (var j:int in oldData_array[2]['content']) {
        if ((oldData_array[2]['content'][j]['id'] == newData_array[2]['content'][w]['id']) && (oldData_array[2]['content'][j]['last_mod'] != newData_array[2]['content'][w]['last_mod'])){
            var proxy:MovieClip = loadImage("image/path.jpg");
            // Do stuff to proxy.
        }
    }    
}
```

And your function + listener would look something like this...

```
var proxies:Object = {};
function loadImage(path:String):MovieClip {
    // load Image
    var proxy:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    proxies.path = proxy;

    // Load Image
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    // Once loaded, use the filename as the proxy object's key to find the MovieClip to attach the image.
    proxies[e.data.loaderInfo.filename].addChild(e.data);
}
```

This is just off the top of my head, so you'll need to find the actual variable names, but I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understood your problem but it seems to me that you simply add the according listener in your inner loop.

```
 //take care this is pseudocode

 var parent = ... // some stage object
 for (var w:int=0; w < size1; w++ ) {
     for (var j:int=0; j < size2; j++ ) {
         if(some_condition){
             request = new URLRequest(getNextImagePath();
             urlLoader = new URLLoader();
             urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
             urlLoader.load(request);
         }
     }       
 }

 function onComplete(event:Event) {
     parent.addChild(createImageFromData(this.data));
 }
```